# column delta values

Tags: sqlite

I am planning to store query data in sqlite3 database.

I have these fields in sqlite3

```
UNIX_EPOCH, CUMULATIVE_QUERY_RATE
1452128581, 150
1452128582, 190
1452128583, 220
1452128584, 270
```

I want to get queries-per-second column as below:

```
QPS
0
40
30
50
```

how do I do it in sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to subtract the value of the previous second:

```sql
SELECT unix_epoch,
       (SELECT T1.cumulative_query_rate - T2.cumulative_query_rate
        FROM SuperSecretTableName AS T2
        WHERE T1.unix_epoch - 1 = T2.unix_epoch
       ) AS qps
FROM SuperSecretTableName AS T1;
```